# hadoop program not executing.... throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, hadoop, nullpointerexception

```
public class signal_identifier {
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(signal_identifier.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long t = cvGetTickCount();
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    long milliSeconds = 1800000;
    conf.setLong("mapred.task.timeout", milliSeconds);
    Job job = new Job(conf, "TrafficSignalProcessing");
    job.setJarByClass(signal_identifier.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(signal_mapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(signal_reducer.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(VideoInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/traffic_signal.mp4"));

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/ouputv"));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);

}
```

}

**Mapper Class:**

```
  public class signal_mapper extends Mapper<Text, VideoObject, Text, IntWritable> {

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(signal_mapper.class); 
private static OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber;
private static IplImage currentFrame;
private static IplImage frame;
private static IplImage imgHSV;
private static IplImage imgThresholdr;
private static IplImage imgThresholdg;
private static IplImage imgC;

static int LowerRed = 160;
static int UpperRed = 180;
static int LowerGreen = 40;
static int UpperGreen = 80;

CvArr mask;
//private static final int FOURCC = CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D');
public void map(Text key, VideoObject value, Context context, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getVideoByteArray());
    LOG.info("Log__VideoConverter__byteArray: "+ byteArrayInputStream.available());

    String fileName = key.toString();
    int id = value.getId();
    long differencer = 0;
    long differenceg = 0;
    long lStartTime = 0;
    String flag = "start";
    //LocalFileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(context.getConfiguration());
    Path filePath = new Path("/tmp", fileName);
    //Path resFile = new Path("/tmp", "res_"+fileName);
    System.out.println("File to Process :"+filePath.toString());
    //FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(filePath, true);
    //out.write(value.getVideoByteArray());
    //out.close();
    try{
        grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(filePath.toString());
        grabber.start();
        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
        CvSize frameSize = new CvSize(grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight());
        currentFrame = cvCreateImage(frameSize, 8, 3);
        IplImage cropped;// = cvCreateImage(frameSize, 8, 3);

        CvRect r = new CvRect(250, 40, 350, 350);

        System.out.println("Video processing .........started");

        while(queryFrame()) {
            cvClearMemStorage(storage);
            if(flag.equals("start")){
                lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
            }
            cvSetImageROI(currentFrame, r);
            cropped = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(currentFrame), currentFrame.depth(),currentFrame.nChannels());
            // Copy original image (only ROI) to the cropped image
            cvCopy(currentFrame, cropped);

            imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(cropped), 8, 3);

            cvCvtColor(cropped, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);


            imgThresholdr = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(cropped), 8, 1);


            imgThresholdg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(cropped), 8, 1);


            imgC = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(cropped),8,1);

            cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(LowerRed,150,75,0), cvScalar(UpperRed, 255, 255, 0), imgThresholdr);
            cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(LowerGreen,150,75,0), cvScalar(UpperGreen, 255, 255, 0), imgThresholdg);


            Dimension positionr = getCoordinates(imgThresholdr);
            int posr = positionr.width+positionr.height;
            Dimension positiong = getCoordinates(imgThresholdg);
            int posg = positiong.width+positiong.height;
            //&& !flag.equalsIgnoreCase("red")      && !flag.equalsIgnoreCase("green")  
            if(posr > 255 && posr < 265 ){

                flag = "red";

            }else {

                long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();

                differenceg = (lEndTime - lStartTime) - differencer;
                output.collect(new Text("Green Color found at second- => "),new IntWritable((int)differenceg/1000));
                //System.out.println("Green Color found at second: " + differenceg/1000);

            }

            if(posg > 430 && posg < 440){
                flag = "green"; 

            }else{
                long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();

                differencer = (lEndTime - lStartTime) - differenceg;
                output.collect(new Text("Red Color found at second- => "),new IntWritable((int)differencer/1000));
                //System.out.println("Red Color found at second: " + differencer/1000);

            }
        }
        grabber.stop();
        System.out.println("Video processing .........Completed");

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static boolean queryFrame() throws Exception {
 try {  
    IplImage frame = grabber.grab();

    if (frame != null) {
        cvConvertImage(frame, currentFrame, 0);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }catch(com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception fge)  {
     return false;
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
     return false;
 }
}

static Dimension getCoordinates(IplImage thresholdImage) {
      int posX = 0;
      int posY = 0;
      CvMoments moments = new CvMoments();
      cvMoments(thresholdImage, moments, 1);
      double momX10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
      double momY01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
      double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);
      posX = (int) (momX10 / area);
      posY = (int) (momY01 / area);
      return new Dimension(posX, posY);
  }
```

}

**Reducer Class:**

```
 public class signal_reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        sum += values.next().get();
    }
    output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
}
```

Wait I'll post my stack trace for Exception

Comment: please post stack tarce of exception

Comment: dude post exception too so we can get the info about null pointer....

Comment: 14/04/21 16:34:43 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local492819261_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.getSerializer(SerializationFactory.java:73)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:970)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:673)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)

Comment: here is the exception